# How to track Amazon AWS S3 bucket downloads using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-analytics

I'm using AWS S3 as my CDN to store files. Often these are directly linked from places all over the world. I'd like to track the file downloads in the S3 bucket using Google Analytics. It appears Google Analytics Measurement Protocol may be able to do this. But since I'm new to both the AWS environment and GAMP, I was hoping I'm not the first to ever do this. Anyone know of a way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible without you doing extra work on top.

You could create a proxy site that, when hit, records an event to Google Analytics and then redirects to the download page/bucket.

You could also maybe have some script/job/etc scrape events from the AWS dashboards and write them to Google Analytics, although this would probably be less than real-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on logging for the buckets you care about, then download the little logfile fragments that Amazon delivers and feed them into an off-the-shelf analytics package such as Webalizer.  If you're willing to spend the time and effort to build a pipeline and massage the data so that it fits.

I've written about how to do that here:

https://www.expatsoftware.com/articles/2007/11/roll-your-own-web-stats-for-amazon-s3.html

If you just want the reports today, there are a handful of 3rd party services built around doing this for you, so if you have ~$10/month to spend that's probably the best solution.

S3stat (https://www.s3stat.com/) is my suggestion.  But then it should be since it's also my product.